# Firebase Polymer 1.x Configuration Error

Tags: firebase, polymer

I was working on my firebase project using polymer. It was working for a while and then i changed the project name in the .firebaserc file, i wanted to use another firebase app for the backend. 
Issue is my firebase-app element fails to intialize, I have placed all element configurations such as auth-domain correctly to my new app but still doesnt work

Comment: What's not working? Do you get any errors? Please edit your question so that it's more clear to us.

Comment: thanks for your response bro, 
If forgot to change the attribute names of the firebase app element from camel case to hyphenated. I got frustrated. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Oppps my bad, I forgot to change the firebase-app element attributes from camel case to kebab case.